# MVC.Grid : how to call @Html.AjaxGrid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, mvcgrid.net

I am working on Mvc.Grid ([Grid.MVC5](http://mvc-grid.azurewebsites.net/Grid/Ajax?mainParam=mainValue)) and using its ajax-grid.

To call ajax-grid we have to call partial view from view as given below:-

```
@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("AjaxGrid", new { tableName = "", type = ""}))
```

Can we call it using jQuery, I have tried below but didn't work, TIA.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { tableName: TableName_, type: SelectedType },
        url: @Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("AjaxGrid"))
 });
```

Partial view:-

```
 public ActionResult AjaxGrid()
        {   
            return PartialView("_KitchensData", FilterData());
        }
 public IEnumerable<KitchenModel> FilterData()
        {
            ViewBag.TableName = "SK_Kitchen";
            KitchenModel model = new KitchenModel();
            KitchenModel result = kitchenAccess.KitchenSearch(model);
            IEnumerable<KitchenModel> _Kitchens = new List<KitchenModel>();
            if (result != null)
            {
                if (result._Kitchens.Count > 0)
                {
                    _Kitchens = result._Kitchens;
                    return _Kitchens;
                }
            }
            return _Kitchens;
        }
```

Comment: can you paste your `AjaxGrid` method here ? which returning you a partial view?

Comment: have updated my question, pl check..

Comment: Replace `@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("AjaxGrid", new { tableName = "", type = ""}))
` with `@Html.AjaxGrid(Url.Action("AjaxGrid"))` as you are not passing any parameters to this method

Comment: @SunilChaudhary I searched a while and found a way with jquery load. I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

can you try Jquery load method to parse your partial view in jquery.

```
//html
<div id="targetDiv"> </div>

// js
$("#targetDiv").load('@Url.Action("AjaxGrid", new { tableName = "", type = ""})')
```

Comment: it loaded ajax grid but grid not working like filters not there , paging is there but not working..

Comment: @SunilChaudhary also I found ajaxify method can you take a look at this link https://gridmvcajax.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: Hi Sunil any solution. same here the filters and pagination is not working